# How to store the text from a .txt file into a variable

Tags: c++

I want to save the text from a `.txt` file as a `char` variable on C++. I have tried:

```
char fileData;
fstream myFile;
myFile.open("file name");
fileData = myFile;
myFile.close();
cout<<fileData;
```

But it is wrong, I get an error `invalid user-defined conversion from 'std::fstream {aka std::basic_fstream<char>}' to 'int' [-fpermissive]`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: For starters, `char fileData;` can only hold a single character.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes I know

Comment: Does your file only contain a single character?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes it only contains the letter A

Comment: Then `fileData = myFile.get();` should work (if you don't care about checking for errors). Also you should be using `ifstream` instead of `fstream` if you only read from the file, without writing to it.

Comment: Someone answered me , `fileData = myFile.get();` works too. I don't see aby difference between fstream and ifstream. [link](https://www.guru99.com/cpp-file-read-write-open.html) check this link... I learned about ofstream and ifstream here... it says that fstream does what ifstream does too.

Comment: `>>` will skip whitespace by default, while `.get()` will give you a space as a character. As for `ifstream` vs `fstream`, if both work, why use the one with extra unnecessary features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After opening a file, you also need to read it in order to obtain its data in a variable.

Also, I noticed that you didn't specify if you were reading a file, or writing to a file.

You can obtain the contents of the file in this manner:

```
myfile>>fileData;
```

You can specify whether the file is to be opened in read mode or write mode, by ios::in or ios::out respectively.

```
myfile.open ("demo.txt", ios::out| ios::in );
```